# Is it possible to build only `redis` from `docker-compose.yml`?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis

I have a docker compose file that has 2 services `redis` & `web`:

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:7.2.4-alpine
    container_name: redis_web_dev
    env_file:
      - ../../.env.development
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    command: redis-server --save 60 1 --loglevel warning --requirepass 123abc
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data
  web:
    image: nextjs-sqlite:0.0.1
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: docker/production/Dockerfile
      target: development
    container_name: web_dev
    env_file:
      - ../../.env.development
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      # - .:/app
      - ../../data:/data
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      redis:
        condition: service_healthy
    command: sh -c "sh ./scripts/run.sh"
volumes:
  redis_data:
    driver: local
```

I only want to build `redis` so I use:

```bash
docker compose -f docker/development/docker-compose.yml build redis
```

but it doesn't show any output or error. It just closes the terminal.

If I run `web`, it gives some output & starts building:

```bash
docker compose -f docker/development/docker-compose.yml build web
```

What's the issue? `web` depends on `redis` but not the other way around so it should work but it doesn't.

Currently, I'm building the whole thing with:

```bash
docker compose -f docker/development/docker-compose.yml build
```

And then only starting `redis` with:

```bash
docker compose -f docker/development/docker-compose.yml up -d redis
```

This works perfectly.

But I'm curious is this how I should go about it? Or is it possible to build `redis` from `docker-compose.yml` & then start it up?

Comment: But there's nothing to build for redis? You are using an existing image, just exiting is expected behavior.

Comment: oh, that makes sense. so if i use `docker compose -f docker/development/docker-compose.yml up -d redis` directly without building anything... then it should work, right?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Answer (score 0):

As [Teemu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6845813/teemu-risikko) said in the comments, redis uses an existing image so there is nothing to build & exiting is the expected behavior.

I can directly run `docker compose -f docker/development/docker-compose.yml up -d redis` to start a redis server where `redis` is my service name. No need to build beforehand.